# Creating array based on similar group of elements from another array

Tags: javascript

I have array arrInt  [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0]. Now i need to create array edge such that based on the values of arrInt, if element containing 0's matches with other element 0's then source of edge will be the index and target will be index of other element. Result of edges is shown below. How can I do this in javascript?

```
       var edges = [];

       edges.push({
            source: ,
            target: 
        });

      edges = [{source: 0, destination: 1},{source: 0, destination: 4},{source: 0, destination: 13}, {source: 1, destination: 4},{source: 0,   destination: 13}, {source: 4, destination: 13},{source: 8, destination: 9} {source: 2, destination: 3}, {source: 2, destination: 5},{source: 2, destination: 6},{source: 2, destination: 9}, {source: 2, destination: 10}, {source: 2, destination: 11}, {source: 2, destination: 12},
   {source: 3, destination: 5},{source: 3, destination: 6},{source: 3, destination: 9},{source: 3, destination: 12},{source: 5, destination: 6},{source: 5, destination: 9},{source: 5, destination: 10},{source: 5, destination: 11},{source: 5, destination: 12},{source: 6, destination: 9},{source: 6, destination: 10},{source: 6, destination: 11},{source: 6, destination: 12},{source: 9, destination: 10},{source: 9, destination: 11},{source: 9, destination: 12},{source: 10, destination: 11},{source: 10, destination: 12},{source: 11, destination: 12}]
```

Comment: It is not clear how you generated the *edges* array. What is the algorithm?

Comment: Are interested in not only matching of 0-s?

Comment: No even 1's as well as 2's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var edges = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arrInt.length; i++)
    for(var j = i + 1; j < arrInt.length; j++)
        if(arrInt[i] === arrInt[j])
            edges.push({ source: i, target: j });
```

`edges` will contains all possible pairs of `i` and `j` where `arrInt[i]` is equal to `arrInt[j]`. Edges are ordered by `(source, target)`.

Then array can be sorted by corresponding `arrInt` values.

```
edges.sort(function (p1, p2) { return arrInt[p1.source] - arrInt[p2.source]; });
```